# Ubuntu CORE SSH key

Tags: login, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I have the same problem as describe in the [SSH to a login to Ubuntu Core on Raspberry Pi requires password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867244/ssh-to-a-login-to-ubuntu-core-on-raspberry-pi-requires-password).
I create a SSH key with Ubuntu MATE 16.04 installed on a VirtualBox VM
The key was created with the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys webpage instructions.
I transfert the public key on my SSO account.
When I boot my Raspberry Pi 3, I do the installation process and I have provided my account information.
To connect to the RPi3, I tried the following different methods.

- My SSO usersname with the RSA key pathphrase.
- My SSO email with the RSA key pathphrase.
- My SSO email with SSO password.
- My SSO username with SSO password.
- Ubuntu / ubuntu.
- My SSO username with no password.
  None of these methods allowed me to login.
  Thanks.

Comment: How exactly are you connecting to the Pi?

Comment: I connect directly from the keyboard connected to the RPi.
I also try with an SSH connection but the result is the same.

Comment: The right combination is
`ssh -i <path-to-SSO-private-key> <SSO-username>@<device-ip>`

Comment: Foxrider83 and that's why I asked how *exactly* you're connecting. @Manik do post an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right combination is `ssh -i <path-to-SSO-private-key> <SSO-username>@<device-ip>`